# Slow join depending on which condition is used outside of it

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, database-performance

I have two tables: `users` and `notifications`. Both have around 500 000 rows.

A user may have notifications.

I have created a view `user_notifications` which groups notifications by `user_id`:

```sql
SELECT
    user_id,
    count(*) as notification_count,
    ...
FROM notifications
GROUP BY user_id
```

This is the query I use to find users and how many notifications the user has:

```sql
SELECT
    user_id
    name,
    user_notifications.notification_count,
    ...
FROM users
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        notification_count,
        ...
    FROM user_notifications
    WHERE user_id = users.user_id
) user_notifications ON TRUE
WHERE name ILIKE '%John Doe%'
```

The column `user_id` is indexed in both tables and so is `users.name` (GIN gin_trgm_ops).

This query yields one result and is quite slow (800ms). According to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the index on `notifications.user_id` isn't used when joining.

However, if I don't use the view, but join and group `notifications` directly, the index is used and the query is fast (10ms).

Also, if I use the view and query for `user_id` instead of `name`, i.e. `WHERE user_id = '1'`, the index is used and the query is fast.

Why is postgres using the index on `notifications.user_id` when I'm querying for `user_id` but not for `name`? And why is it using the index when I'm not querying the view?

(using PostgreSQL 12.5)

PS. The queries and data are simplified but these are the interesting parts. I know I don't have to use a view but it would simplify and make other queries cleaner.

**Update:**

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output:

```sql
Merge Left Join  (cost=66189.69..79940.44 rows=50 width=275) (actual time=21124.540..21124.636 rows=1 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: ((users.user_id)::text = (notifications.user_id)::text)
  ->  Sort  (cost=354.77..354.89 rows=50 width=269) (actual time=2.379..2.416 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: users.user_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=160.39..353.36 rows=50 width=269) (actual time=2.338..2.365 rows=1 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((name)::text ~~* '%John Doe%'::text)
              Heap Blocks: exact=1
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on name_index  (cost=0.00..160.38 rows=50 width=0) (actual time=2.309..2.315 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((name)::text ~~* '%John Doe%'::text)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=65834.92..73334.92 rows=500000 width=39) (actual time=7305.864..17762.391 rows=477778 loops=1)
        Group Key: notifications.user_id
        ->  Sort  (cost=65834.92..67084.92 rows=500000 width=6) (actual time=7305.828..10839.863 rows=477779 loops=1)
              Sort Key: notifications.user_id
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8248kB
              ->  Seq Scan on notifications  (cost=0.00..11667.00 rows=500000 width=6) (actual time=0.016..3485.382 rows=499998 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.472 ms
Execution Time: 21126.607 ms
```

For some reason the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` takes about 20 sec while the query without it takes 800ms.

The reason I use `LATERAL` is because a regular join resulted in the index not being used when I joined the `notifications` table directly (i.e. skipped the view completely).

Comment: There isn't much point in asking a performance or planner question and then simplifying the queries. Even with the real queries we'd want the output of EXPLAIN ANALYSE. I don't understand what your LATERAL is doing in that join though - presumably you are forced to do it that way in the real query?

Comment: One thing that makes your query slow, is the usage of a very small setting for work_mem. Even 8MB of data has to be sorted on disk, which is slow and takes over 7 seconds. Use a larger setting. I don't understand the usage of a LATERAL join, nor the subquery. Why do you need this?

Comment: Increasing work_mem did speed up the query to 300ms, but it's still not using the index on `notifications.user_id `. As I said, if I query for `case_id` instead of `name`, the index is used but I don't understand how the condition outside the join can affect the time it takes to join if the condition returns the same amount of rows (1).

The reason I use LATERAL is because a regular join resulted in the index not being used when I joined the notifications table directly (i.e. skipped the view completely).